# Need help to increase code coverage for boolean, presently only 63% achieved

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller

Here is my Class:

```
public class copymanualComp {

    public string id;
    public String inputmode{get;set;}
    public boolean copypaste{get;set;}
    public boolean manual{get;set;}

    public copymanualComp(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  
        R_PG__c grid=[select id,R_Input_Mode__c from R_PG__c where id=:id];    
        inputmode=grid.R_Input_Mode__c; 
        if(inputmode=='Copy/Paste'){
        copypaste=true;
        }else if(inputmode=='Manually'){
            manual=true;
        }
    }    

}
```

Here is the Test class:

```
@isTest
public class copymanualComp_Test 
{

    public static testMethod void Copy()
    {
     Test.startTest();

         R_PG__c din = new R_PG__c(Name='sand');
         insert din;
         din.Name = 'sanc';
         update din;
         system.debug('din.id'+din.id);

         ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',din.id);
         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(din);
         copymanualComp  rp = new copymanualComp(sc);

         R_PG__c pg=new R_PG__c(Name='t1);
         insert pg;


     Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

The lines marked in red below are not covered:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Test.startTest();

    R_PG__c din = new R_PG__c(Name='sand', inputMode='Copy/Paste');
    insert din;

    PageReference yourPage = Page.YourPage; //change to your own page's name
    Test.setCurrentPage(yourPage);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',din.id);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(din);
    copymanualComp  rp = new copymanualComp(sc);
    System.assertEquals(true, rp.copypaste);

    din.inputMode = 'Manually';
    update din;

    copymanualComp  rp2 = new copymanualComp(sc);
    System.assertEquals(true, rp.manual);

    Test.stopTest();
```

Note:

1. You should include asserts in your test case. Remember, you should test something in your test code, not just aiming for the code coverage.
2. Reading your code, I kind of have a feeling you are not quite familiar with apex language or test case writing. Going through the apex developer's guide is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm new to Apex and yes definitely I will go through developers guide. Thanks a lot for your kind advice and help:)

Answer (score 2):

You have to call your fields to perform the unit test on them, where you'll get code coverage as an added advantage. 
Try below code(not tested) for your test class method.

```
public static testMethod void Copy()
{
    Test.startTest();

     R_PG__c din = new R_PG__c(Name='sand');
     insert din;
     din.Name = 'sanc';
     update din;
     system.debug('din.id'+din.id);

     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',din.id);
     ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(din);
     copymanualComp  rp = new copymanualComp(sc);

    // check the class fields and make sure your requirements get satisfied
    System.assertEquals(false, rp.copypaste);
    System.assertEquals(false, rp.manual);

    //check for some another use case : inputmode=copy/paste
    din.R_Input_Mode__c = 'Copy/Paste';
    update din;

    sc = new ApexPages.standardController(din);
    rp = new copymanualComp(sc);
    System.assertEquals(true, rp.copypaste);

    //check for some another use case : inputmode=manual
    din.R_Input_Mode__c = 'Manually';
    update din;

    sc = new ApexPages.standardController(din);
    rp = new copymanualComp(sc);
    System.assertEquals(true, rp.manual);

     R_PG__c pg=new R_PG__c(Name='t1);
     insert pg;


    Test.stopTest();

}
```

Also it's good to introduce default values for your class fields in the constructor.

```
public copymanualComp(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    copypaste = false;
    manual = false;

    // your code
}
```